# How can I write an int into a file

Tags: python, string, file, io, int

When I try to write into another file, I get an error saying:

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not int
```

How can I write an int to a file? Below is my current code

```
infile = open("milk.in","r").readlines()
outfile = open("milk.out","w")

a, b = infile[0].split()
a, b = int(a), int(b)

sum = a + b

outfile.write(sum)
outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`write()` takes only `string` as argument. Convert `sum` to `string`.

```
infile = open("milk.in","r").readlines()
outfile = open("milk.out","w")

a, b = infile[0].split()
a, b = int(a), int(b)

sum = a + b

outfile.write(str(sum))
outfile.close()
```

However, you should read [file I/O](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write an integer directly to a file. you have to convert the `int` into a `string` using `str` function and then write it to the file

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can't simply write the integer to file and it will be written in string form.

However, If you want value to be stored as it is (in your case, it's an integer) and later want to retrieve it, then you can use pickle module of python

```
import pickle
pickle.dump()      
pickle.load()
```

So give pickle a try and let your values stored in the format that you want them to stored in file

http://effbot.org/librarybook/pickle.htm [pickle introduction]